# Mysql update: How to search for string with quotes 

Tags: mysql

How can I search for quotes with mysql update command?
I'm using the following command, but it can't find anything.

```
update ibf_posts set post = replace(post, 'src="style_emoticons', 'src="/public/style_emoticons');
```

Comment: do a select first to see if you find anything where post = your criteria. `Select post from ibf_posts where post LIKE '%src="style_emoticons%'`  my guess is nothing is updating because you have no records exactly matching your search criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try escaping them:

```
update ibf_posts set post = replace(post, 'src=\"style_emoticons', 'src=\"/public/style_emoticons');
```

Comment: @Crazy_Bash - Did this really work? `'src=\"style'` is exactly the same as `'src="style'` :-?

Comment: strange, maybe mysql 5 workes different? I'm also working with putty

Answer (score 0):

```
update ibf_posts set post = 'src="style_emoticons' where POST = 'src="/public/style_emoticons');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine *if there is a match*:

```
SELECT replace('<a src="style_emoticons">', 'src="style_emoticons', 'src="/public/style_emoticons')
```

... prints:

```
<a src="/public/style_emoticons">
```